# Different TCA Configuration depeding on ColPos value?

Tags: typo3, backend

is it possible to have an alternative TCA-Configuration depeding on the ColPos value?
I was testing the cropVariants for CType Image. I want different cropVariants for several cols in tt_content.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible by default but you can take a look at https://github.com/sup7even/image_cropper_configuration how you can manipulate the configuration on the fly. The example however still needs to be adopted to fit your needs with the colpos.